# PHP: variables not working after running "if" command

Tags: javascript, php, html

Recenty i was planning on creating a database processor and after processing the login info the varables that contained the data couldn't be found (dissapeared) and whatever i would try to run in the "if" that verified the login info after the popup i created in javascript wouldn't appear on the screen.

The login info is sent from a login screen, and this is the code that sends the data:
    
    Login

```
<form action="login1.php" method="post">
Username:<br><input type="text" name="uname">
<br>
Password:<br><input type="Password" name="pass">
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Login" name="submit">
</form>

</fieldset>
<form action="MainScreen.html" method='get'>
<button type='Submit'>Inapoi la pagina principala</button>

</form>
```

This is the screen that proceses the login info

```
<?php
require('sql_connect.php');
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $username=mysql_escape_string($_POST['uname']);
    $password=mysql_escape_string($_POST['pass']);
    global $z;
    $z=substr($username, 0, -1);
    $q=$z;
    ///mysql_query($z);
    if (!$_POST['uname'] or !$_POST['pass']){
        echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
            window.alert('Nu ati completat toate campurile necesare.\nVa rugam incercati din nou.')
            window.location.href='login.php'
            </SCRIPT>");
    }

    $sql= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `xii f` WHERE `IdPar` = '$username' AND `Password` = '$password'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0)
    {
        echo$z;
        echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
            window.alert('Bine ati venit domnule/doamna ".$z."')
            window.location.href='login1.php'
        </SCRIPT>");
        /* Here i tried to run a table, but it doesn't seem to work
        $sq= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `absente s1` WHERE `Nume` ='$z'");
        echo'
            <table border="2" style= "background-color: white; color: black; margin: 3 auto; font-size:95%;" >
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Absenta</th>
                    <th>Materie</th>
                    <th>Motivat</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        <tbody>';

        while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sq) )
          echo "<tr>
          <td>{$row['Absenta']}</td>
          <td>{$row['Materie']}</td>
          <td>{$row['Motivat']}</td>
        </tr>";

        echo'
        </tbody>
    </table>';

    */
    }
    else{
        $sql= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Profesori` WHERE `IdProf` = '$username' AND `Password` = '$password'");
        if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0)
        {
            $k=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Profesori` WHERE `sex`='M' AND `IdProf` = '$username' AND `Password` = '$password'");
            if(mysql_num_rows($k) > 0){
                echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
                window.alert('Bine ati venit domnule ".$z."')
                window.location.href='login1.php'
                </SCRIPT>");
            }
            else{
                echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
                    window.alert('Bine ati venit doamna ".$z."')
                    window.location.href='login1.php'
                    </SCRIPT>");
            }
        }
        else{
            $sql= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Diriginte` WHERE `Id` = '$username' AND `Password` = '$password'");
            if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0)
            {
                echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
            window.alert('Bine ati venit domnule ".$z."')
            window.location.href='login1.php'
            </SCRIPT>");
            }
            else {
                echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
            window.alert('Nume de utilizator sau parola gresite. Va rugam reintroduceti.')
            window.location.href='login.php'
            </SCRIPT>");
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

The sql_connect.php file is used to esablish the connection to the serv and the database
I must mention that the code is written in a HTML formatted file in the  division altrough i think it doesn't affect the php script. This is the code for the page formatting:

```
<style>

header {
    background-color:white;
    color:white;
    height:5%;
    width:80%;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
}

details {
    background-color:#B0B0B0;
    color:white;
    height:15%;
    width:80%;
    font-size:180%;
    font-family: "Magneto";
    float:left;
    text-align:center;

}
nav {
    line-height:30px;
    background-color:white;
    height:100%;
    width:10%;
    float:left;

}

section {
    background-color:#F0F0F0 ;
    width:20%;
    height:60%;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
}
aside {
    background-color:#F0F0F0;
    width:40%;
    height:60%;
    font-family: "High Tower Text";
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
}
summary{
    background-color:#F0F0F0;
    width:20%;
    height:60%;
    text-align:left;
    float:left;
}
article {
    background-color:#B0B0B0;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:'Copperplate Gothic Bold';
    height:15%;
    width:80%;  
    float:left;
}
background-color:red;
</style>
```

td;lr Variables are dissparearing after running the "if" command.

EDIT: Solved issue. Turns out it was due to the `window.location.href='login1.php'` command that reloaded the page

Comment: You shouldn't use GET forms as links to return to the main page, you should use `a` elements. Start by replacing that second form to a `<a href="MainScreen.html">Inapoi la pagina principala</a>`. For the login form, I would recomend using AJAX. At least checking through javascript if the fields are empty before sending the form, instead of doing so afterwards, so as to avoid the first validation in the login1.php document. If you don't follow this recommendation, at least don't query the db if one of the fields is empty, as you are doing currently.

Comment: "if" is not a command. It's a conditional statement.

Comment: Also, the "language" attribute in `script` tags is deprecated. You should consider using at least some basic encryption for the stored passwords in the database. Use PHP5 methods such as mysqli to improve security and avoid using deprecated methods (all the mysql_ family). After these improvements, it would probably be wise to rewrite the database structure as to include all users in a same table, and then define their roles by the use of a stored value (1 for student, 2 for teacher, 0 for administrator or whatever Diriginte means).

Comment: What do you intend to do with the statement `global $z;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking into account most of the comments I made on the question, I created a functional replica of your application, making some of the much needed corrections.

**login.php**

```
<form name="loginForm" action="login-validation.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validate()">
    Username:&emsp;<input type="text" name="uname"><br/>
    Password:&emsp;<input type="Password" name="pass"><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Login" name="submit">
</form>

<a href="MainScreen.html">Inapoi la pagina principala</a>

<script>
function validate() {
    var uname = document.forms["loginForm"]["uname"].value;
    var pass = document.forms["loginForm"]["pass"].value;
    if ((uname == null || uname == "") || (pass == null || pass == "")) {
        alert("Please fill out all the fields.");
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

**login-validation.php**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $con = new mysqli("localhost","root","","stackoverflow");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Database Error: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit("<br/><a href='login.php'>Try again</a>");
    }

    $username = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['uname']);
    $password = $_POST['pass'];

    // Fetch user by username & close the connection to the database
    $result = $con->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'");
    $con->close();

    // Retrieve data
    $row = $result->fetch_row();

    // Check if there's a match
    if(!empty($row)) {

        // Validate password
        if(strcmp($password, $row[2]) == 0) {

            // Save Result in Session for future uses
            $_SESSION['uid'] = $row[0]; // users.id
            $_SESSION['username'] = $row[1]; // users.username
            $_SESSION['password'] = $row[2]; // users.password
            $_SESSION['role'] = $row[3]; // users.role

            // Exit sending a message to the now logged user
            exit("Bine ati venit domnule/doamna ".$row[1]);
        } else {

            // Exit if password doesn't match, provide link for trying again
            exit("Incorrect password<br/><a href='login.php'>Try again</a>");
        }
    }

    // If there was no match in the query, throw message and exit
    exit("Invalid data<br/><a href='login.php'>Try again</a>");
}
// Create a link to the login page and exit if there was no POST data
exit("<a href='login.php'>Login</a>");
```

The database structure for the table `users`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `username` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
    `password` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
    `role` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1'
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `username`, `password`, `role`) VALUES
(1, 'student', 'student', 0),
(2, 'teacher', 'teacher', 1),
(3, 'other', 'other', 0);

ALTER TABLE `users`
    ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    ADD UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`);


ALTER TABLE `users`
    MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=2;
```

Some of the still missing proper adjustments:

- Encryption for the stored passwords
- Control of access to the login page (redirect logged users)
- Control of access to the login validation page
- Better management of what happens to logged users
- Better management (more user friendly) of what happens when login fails

Answer (score -3):

you can not get variables in this way because once you are done with echoing to browser your request gets over. To use same variables on another redirected php page you need to store your variables in the session like:

$_SESSION["username"] = $_POST['uname'];
$_SESSION["password"] = $_POST['pass'];

and get them when you want with $_SESSION["username"]